# "How much it cost?" or "How much does it cost?"

Tags: questions, do-support

I want your help please.
I know that correct question is "How much does it cost?" but I saw many questions like this with different structure like this "How much it cost?"
So, which of these two is correct?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"How much does it cost?" is the correct one.

"How much it cost?" is understandable, but incorrect - a (very) beginner would be expected to use this.